# a4j:commandLink with onClick return true or false not properly working

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

My code is like below,

```html
<a4j:commandLink  oncomplete="openSignatureModel();" id="requestText"  reRender="sigPassword"  title="Send Prescription"
actionListener="#{patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescriptionId}"
onclick="return pharmacyCheck('#{row}');"> 
<f:param name="sendPrescriptionId" value="#{patientNotePrescriptionVar.id}" />
<f:param name="processOfPrescription" value="Send" />
<h:graphicImage value="/images/send-prescribe.png" style="border:0;"></h:graphicImage>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

and my java script is like...

```
function pharmacyCheck(rowID) {
    var a = document.getElementById("prescriptionId:patientNotePresListId:"+rowID+":pharmacyRcopiaId");
    if(a.value == -1) {
        alert("Please select Pharmacy");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Actually when it returns true it should call **patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescriptionId**  right?

But it's not calling the same.... Is there any reason why?

Comment: It might be the use of `actionListener` which IIRC requires a special method signature. Why don't you use `action="..."` instead?

Comment: See my answer, I had faced your problem before and that's the solution I've found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you see the generated HTML, something like this will be in the onclick method of the button/link:

```
onclick="return pharmacyCheck('#{row}');;A4J.AJAX.Submit(..."
```

So the onclick is returning at the beginning and the ajax submit will not be sent. To solve your problem, use your javascript method in this way:

```
<a4j:commandLink onclick="if (!pharmacyCheck('#{row}')) return false;" ...>
```

EDIT: Further explanation:

When you have a JavaScript code like this:

```
function X() {
    return false;
    alert("this alert won't be shown =(");
}
```

As obviously stated, the alert won't fire never. So, checking the generated HTML for onclick (specially formatted to see the similarities):

```
onclick="
    return functionX();
    alert('this alert will not display either X_x');
    A4J.AJAX.Submit(...
"
```

The onclick code won't fire because you're returning something before executing the code. The change will just intercept the `false` value and do a return, in case your method returns `true`, the rest of the code will be executed.

Note: By default, any javascript method that doesn't return anything, returns false.

Comment: No I checked... #{row} will return rowIndex of datatable and hence it's something like below **javascript:return pharmacyCheck('4');;A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id_jsp_1779705005_0','prescriptionId',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){openSignatureModel();},'similarityGroupingId':'prescriptionId:patientNotePresListId:4:requestText','parameters':{'prescriptionId:patientNotePresListId:4:requestText':'prescriptionId:patientNotePresListId:4:requestText','processOfPrescription':'Send','sendPrescriptionId':1002} ,'actionUrl':'/Oscer/pages/PatientsNotePreDetail.jsf'} );return false;**

Comment: Well, I don't really know how the whole generated HTML will be for your specific link, but as any other JavaScript method, if you return anything at some place, the rest of the code won't be executed. That's why you should add a validation before returning anything.

Comment: OMG you are perfect dear... I added what you said in my code **if(!pharmacyCheck('#{row}')) return false;** and it worked... but still I could not understand what this line mean... Can you please explain me...

Comment: Does this mean by default it returns true? and my next code will be execute and if my return from pharmacyCheck function is false then it will explicitly return false? Is it so???